# Node js: how to register helper with express-handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to register helper with "express-handlebars", but getting an error "expbs.registerHelper is not a function".

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');

var paginate = require('handlebars-paginate');
expbs.registerHelper('paginate', paginate);

const routes = require('./routes/handlers');

app.use(express.static('public'));  

const hbs = expbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/mainLayout'), 
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views/pieces'), 
    helpers: {
        calculation: function(value) {
            return value * 5;
        },
        list: function(value, options) {
            let out = "<ul>";
            for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                out = out + "<li>" +  options.fn(value[i]) + "</li>";
            }
            return out + "</ul>";
        }
    }
});

app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/route1', routes);

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server is starting at port ', 8080);
});
```

How can i register helper with express-handlebars ?

Answer (score 0):

As error says: expbs.registerHelper is not a function in express-handlebars. You are confusing with "handlebars" package. registerhelper is a method in handlebars.

express-handlebars and handlebars are two different packages. I also confused them when I started to learn Node.js. I installed handlebars but I was trying to use express-handlebars methods :)

Your set up is correct. This is how you should call

```
{{calculation 20}} //20 is the argument
```

Whenever you create custom helper, you have to specify the value.